# Avoid inserting duplicates into MySQL while reading an excel file using spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, excel, spring-boot

I am using [spring boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) to read an Excel file. I read the name of each sheet and insert them into a database. I want to check if the name already exists, before inserting the name of the sheet. I want to only insert the name if it doesn't already exist.

How to avoid inserting duplicate names into MySQL while reading an excel file using spring boot?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
public void  insertIntoMysql()
    {
        try { 
            List<Field> fs=new ArrayList<Field>();
            InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("IR21_Update.xlsx");
            XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);  

            for(int i=0;i<wb.getNumberOfSheets();i++)
            {  TableEntity t=new TableEntity(wb.getSheetName(i), "");

        if(!te.findAll().contains(t.getEntityName()))
                {System.out.println(te.findAll().contains(t.getEntityName()));
          te.save(t);

            }}} catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

Comment: I improved the formatting and title for better readability. Please mention if your current code is throwing any error if so mention the error or just allowing duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the exists() method instead of what you are doing? That is what it is there for.

> boolean exists(ID id)
>
> Returns whether an entity with the given id exists.

```
if(!te.exits(wb.getSheetName(i))){
    TableEntity t=new TableEntity(wb.getSheetName(i), "");
    te.save(t)
}
```